# Trying to use ftplib and discord.py together.. having some issues

Tags: python, discord, ftplib

having some issues and hopefully I can get some assistance :D... the code is below

```
from ftplib import FTP
import shutil
import urllib.request as request
from contextlib import closing
import os
import json
import time
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get
with open('variables.json') as f:
    variables = json.load(f)
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!", case_insensitive=True)
ftp = FTP(variables['FTPHOST'], user = variables['USER'], passwd= variables['PASSWORD'])
ftp.cwd(variables['ftppath'])

def uploadThis(path):
    files = os.listdir(path)
    os.chdir(path)
    for f in files:
        if os.path.isfile(path + r'\{}'.format(f)):
            fh = open(f, 'rb')
            ftp.storbinary('STOR %s' % f, fh)
            fh.close()
        elif os.path.isdir(path + r'\{}'.format(f)):
            ftp.mkd(f)
            ftp.cwd(f)
            uploadThis(path + r'\{}'.format(f))
    ftp.cwd('..')
    os.chdir('..')

@client.command(pass_context=True,)
@commands.has_role('Sanitation Engineers')
async def stats(ctx):
    #ftp = FTP(variables['FTPHOST'], user = variables['USER'], passwd= variables['PASSWORD'])
    #ftp.cwd(variables['ftppath'])
    await ctx.send("Foomalyzing and parsing logs, this may take some time..")
    roundOneLink = ""
    roundTwoLink = ""
    path = variables['path']  

    imagePath = variables['imagepath']  
    stylePath = variables['stylepath'] 

    dirList = ftp.nlst()
    logs = []
    for i in dirList:
        if(".log" in i):
            logs.append(i)
    logToParse = (logs[-3])
    parseFolder = logToParse[:-4]
    ftp.retrbinary("RETR " + logToParse, open(logToParse, 'wb').write)

    parseFolder = logToParse[:-4]
    roundOneLink = variables["URLPATH"] + parseFolder + "/"
    os.mkdir(parseFolder)
    desPath = variables['despath'] + parseFolder

    os.system('cmd /c "F: && cd %s && logalyzer -image %s -style %s -o %s %s"' % (path, imagePath, stylePath, parseFolder, logs[-3]))
    ftp.mkd(parseFolder)
    ftp.cwd(parseFolder)
    print(ftp.pwd(), desPath)
    uploadThis(desPath)
    #ftp.cwd("../")
    os.remove(logToParse)
    

    print(ftp.pwd()) 
    logToParse = (logs[-2])
    parseFolder = logToParse[:-4]

    ftp.retrbinary("RETR " + logToParse, open(logToParse, 'wb').write)

    
    roundTwoLink = variables["URLPATH"] + parseFolder + "/"
    os.mkdir(parseFolder)
    desPath = variables['despath'] + parseFolder

    os.system('cmd /c "F: && cd %s && logalyzer -image %s -style %s -o %s %s"' % (path, imagePath, stylePath, parseFolder, logs[-2]))
    ftp.mkd(parseFolder)
    ftp.cwd(parseFolder)
    print (ftp.pwd())
    uploadThis(desPath)
    ftp.cwd("../")

    os.remove(logToParse)

    await ctx.send("Round 1: " + roundOneLink)
    await ctx.send("Round 2: " + roundTwoLink)

    ftp.quit()
client.run(variables['TOKEN'])
```

The code works when I run it the first time around, seems to give me the following error when I run it a second time around without restarting the script altogether.. the error im getting is a NoneType error with no attribute Sendall... it seems to be pointing out this line specifically..

dirList = ftp.nlst()

been hacking away at this all night lol... basiaclly its taking logs from a gaming server.. parsing them, then reuploading them using another program that creates it as a webpage.. any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Got it working.. put the login within the !stats command and added another parameter for upload this to point to the ftp..